# Is there any error logging when mysql query fails?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm curious if there is any error logging by the MySQL database when I execute a query. I know that I call [mysql_error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) to retrieve an error but is there some other logging on database side?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default mysql does not log queries. But you can increase the log level at the sql configuration files. Try the file: `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`and uncomment the line

```
general_log             = 1
```

For performance, it is off by default.

Comment: Caution:  It eats up disk space quite fast.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if it's properly set up, then it should be. It usually is by default. You can get more info in the MySQL documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-logs.html

Also, if you use *nix or BSD, the logs are usually stored in /var/log/ .

Comment: If you read the link you sent: "By default, no logs are enabled."

Comment: I'm really sorry about that. Looks like I've been always working with servers that had it enabled.

Answer (score -2):

what do you mean like empty querys or bad querys?

```
   $sql = mysql_query( select * from table );
// but theres no rows you would right a if statment with mysql_num_rows
if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0){

}else{
// error message here for empty
}

// or
 mysql_query(......)or die(mysql_error());
// this will tell you why its returnig false!
```

Comment: I mean logging in MySQL database not using custom php code  to log errors.