# PHP function doesn't increment int as it should

Tags: php

On my XAMPP server I have a database table on phpMyAdmin. In that table, I have a few columns, and one of them is `id` column (Integer).

I want to get the latest added item's ID, increment it by one and then assign it to a new item that the function adds to the table.

The problem is that whenever there is a new item, it is automatically assigned with 1 as id, nothing above 1.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM items";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        if( $_SESSION["increment"] == "yes"){
            $_SESSION["id"] = $row["id"];
        }else
            $_SESSION["id"]=$_SESSION["id"]+1;
    }
} else {
    $_SESSION["id"] = 1;
}
```

Comment: [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) said what? and `mysqli_error($conn)`?

Comment: This whole thing seems wrong headed to me

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you need well known AUTO_INCREMENT functionality built inside MySQL database. Just define in your database schema for your table that column is AUTO_INCREMENT column type, and it will be automatically incremented by 1 upon each new insert into table.

Comment: Yes, but I need also the id itself on the function for further actions

Comment: Ok, you get it with mysqli->insert_id (http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php)

Answer (score 0):

This will give you last increment Id.

```
 $sql = "SELECT id FROM items order by id DESC LIMIT 0,1";
```

Then you dont want have a while loop to find last increment Id.

Answer (score 0):

> [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) said what? and `mysqli_error($conn)`?

-- Fred-ii-

- The above request by *Fred -ii-*  sums it up, if your `->num_rows` is returning zero or not a number (`false`) then you have an SQL error, so you need to check your [error logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php?rq=1), and check your [database connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7989244/is-there-any-error-logging-when-mysql-query-fails).
- Have you started your session with `session_start`?
- Do you intend that the first `else` calls without brackets, only executing the single following line, `$_SESSION["id"]=$_SESSION["id"]+1;` ?